# FFmpeg real-time audio stream with low latancy

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

Is there any way to capture and stream the sound at near to real speed with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

To record and stream use

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -f rtp rtp://destination_ip:2666?pkt_size=188?buffer_size=16384 -sdp_file stream.sdp
```

To play stream with `ffplay` copy cinfig.sdp file to playing host and start

```
ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp stream.sdp
```